# How to force block complete before coming back to check loop condition iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, dispatch-async

I have a while loop to check condition but the block inside never complete so it is an infinite loop. Here is my code

```
__block BOOL doContinue = YES;
while (doContinue) {
  [NetworkHandle withParam:param url:url complete:^(id result, BOOL error)
  {
    if(...)
       doContinue = NO;
  } okHandler: ^{} retryHandler:^{} ];
}
```

But the complete block never been called so the while loop keeps going.
I tried every answers in this thread: [Wait for async task to finish completion block before returning in app delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914753/wait-for-async-task-to-finish-completion-block-before-returning-in-app-delegate?rq=1)
but they didn't work.

My current approach makes app wait forever

```
__block BOOL doContinue = YES;
while (doContinue) {
  dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

  [NetworkHandle withParam:param url:url complete:^(id result, BOOL error)
  {
    if(...)
       doContinue = NO;
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
  } okHandler: ^{} retryHandler:^{} ];

  dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
  dispatch_release(sema);
}
```

Comment: you can use `@synchronized{...}` block to wait for execution to complete. Let me know once you are done..

Comment: What does `+[NetworkHandle withParam:url:complete:okHandler:retryHandler:]` do? You can only wait for it to finish if it executes asynchronously on another thread/queue. If it executes later on the same thread/queue, then by definition it cannot wait for it to finish.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I tried but it didn't work

Comment: @newacct this method sends param to url server to process and get result back, check if result tells there is still data to load to call [NetworkHandle...] again, if there is no data, set doContinue = NO, but the complete block never completes, the while loop checks doContinue before NetworkHandle can get result back

Comment: @keduadoi: If the completion block is not called, then the loop should not proceed, because it should be stuck waiting for the semaphore to signal. So this does not make sense.