# PFConfig synchronous call

Tags: ios, parse-platform

quick question about **PFConfig**.
Unfortunately, I cannot get my current config in background so I need to call it when the app starts synchronously.

If the network is not available the app freeze on some version of iOS, I was wondering if there is some timeout I can set on the synchronous call.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why it cannot be fetched asynch?

Comment: I have a flag in my config that switch on (or off) a feature on the app. This flag can be updated so every time I run the app I need to check its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main advice is to do the call asynch and design your UI to deal with it.  For example, a first-run-only view controller that says "hi" while it gets ready to run (and a requirement that user must have a network on first run -- highly probable if they just downloaded the app).

In other words, I think its a mistake to force the config call to be synchronous, but here's one way to do it...

```
- (PFConfig *)yuckyGetConfig {
    __block PFConfig *config;
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [PFConfig getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFConfig *config, NSError *error) {
        config = config;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return config;
}
```

The idea is that `dispatch_semaphore_wait` is equivalent to a while loop (but executing far fewer instructions) until the getConfig block has executed.  (This idea thanks to [@Rob, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22915139/294949), though the rest of his advice is particular to the document api).

Comment: I think calling a synch function is wrong as well and you answer is close to the solution. I need to design my app startup to consider that solution.