# Variable becomes nil after if-else clause

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, parse-platform

After execute the query from parse in IF clause and stored in StaffID. I got what i want.

But then after the if/else clause the StaffID variable becomes Nil

Here's the code

```
func StaffIdQuery(DeviceToken: String) -> String
{
    var StaffID = ""
    let StaffIdQuery = PFQuery(className: "Staff")
    StaffIdQuery.whereKey("StaffDeviceToken", equalTo: DeviceToken)
    StaffIdQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && objects != nil {
            StaffID = objects?.valueForKey("StaffID") as! String
            print(StaffID) //This seems fine
        }
        else {
    // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    print(StaffID) //this becomes nil
    return StaffID
}
```

What should i fix to get the query data?

Comment: Is your function `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock `  async?

Comment: Your `StaffIdQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` is an async call which executes 'later' then your `print(StaffID)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it nil or is it an empty string? I bet it's the latter. In Swift, when you declare a var like you do:

```
var StaffID = ""
```

it assumes the type to be `String`, not `String?`. That means it can never be nil.

You're setting the value of StaffID asynchronously, in a background queue, but you print it before that background queue gets a change to set it. If you print it inside the block (which you already do), you'll get the correct value. Without extra synchronization logic, you should never rely on a value of a variable that is set in a different thread/queue.

Comment: Thank you!! I am now understand how getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock works. But if i want to get the query data, which method should i use instead?

Comment: @NuttanichaSanpechvittaya glad I could help! I'm not sure I understand your second question. Do you mean how to query data in Parse?

Answer (score 3):

Your block is asynchronous.  What is happening is that when you call getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock, the system goes off to get that data in the background, and your code continues executing.  You print "StaffID" before it's finished getting the data.  Then, at a later time, the block executes and your staffID gets populated.

Timeline:

1. Send system off for data
2. Print data (it's not there yet)
3. Data arrives, after you've returned null.

You could use a semaphore to wait until the block completes - using something like the top answer to this question: [Wait for async task to finish completion block before returning in app delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914753/wait-for-async-task-to-finish-completion-block-before-returning-in-app-delegate)

I think it would be a better approach though to look at your design and see if you can't handle the results in the block rather than waiting for it, and blocking the main thread waiting for IO.